# Ionic - white screen after ionic serve

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I'm so frustrated right now. I've been trying to fix this for 4 hours and I have no clue what's going on. Earlier today I updated my ionic project to the latest after doing a `ionic doctor check` and it said I should update from `4.4.0` to `4.7.0` and since then my project doesn't work at all. I've tried creating a new project with `ionic start`, that project works fine, until I paste my code over.

When I do `ionic serve` to launch the server, on the first load I get a handful of inexplicable errors:

[image]

And then if I save a document and it rebuilds I just get a blank screen with no errors...

[image]

I have literally no idea what's going on. Please, does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Can you try deleting your "Project_Folder/www" folder and build the project again.

Comment: can you try adding the type in `index.html`? So for the links: `<link href="...." type="text/css"/>` and for all scripts: `<script src="..." type="application/javascript">` not sure if this works